# Django, Jinja -- Dynamically Reference Static Images from using an object attribute (slug)

Tags: python, django, pycharm, jinja2

Forgive my asking of what might be the wrong question, it's my second day of Django.

I've got a model in the database, and the model has the following attributes:

```
   'title': 'Entity title for Entity A',
   'slug': 'entity-a',
   '...': '...'
```

In my .html Jinja template, I want to load multiple entities using a loop. Which works. However, I want to reference some static loaded logo using the `entity.slug`.

Like so...

```
{% for entity in entities %}
            {{ entity.slug }}
            <img src="{% static 'logos/{{entity.slug}}_50x50.png' %}" alt="" class="mr-2 img-thumbnail" width="50">
{% endfor %}
```

See inside IMG tags. Where I have `{{entity.slug}}`.
How can I put it in so the static images will load dynamically?

Atm, it's rendering the {{}} [see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZhUv.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stright approach is to make a property in your `entity` model and use it in template. Like that:

```
# models
class Entity(models.Model):
  ...
  
  @property
  def logo_url(self):
    return 'logos/%s_50x50.png' % self.slug

# tpl
<img src="{% static entity.logo_url %}">
```

But you should consider using [ImageField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ImageField) instead of that hardcoding because it's actually media files (not static).

So if you will have `logo = models.ImageField(...)` you will easily use it in template like `{{ entity.logo.url }}`.

Comment: Do ImageFields store the actual image's data?
I already have the images in file system, just which to reference path.

Comment: They store relative path to it (in db they are char fields).